# Changing the order of integration in three dimensions, of a level curve, $e^{x^2}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Change the order of integration $dx\,dy$ to $dy\,dx$ and evaluate it:

$$\int_0^1\int_{3y}^3 e^{x^2} \, dx \, dy$$

now I now that I can do the following:

$$x=3,\quad x=3y \to y=\frac{1}{3}x$$

Okay now I have one bound for integrating $dy$...where do I go from here? I would prefer algebraic methods rather than looking at graph, I believe this can be done purely algebraically...I tried to graph it, which i haven't learned how to do in three dimension since my class isn't for a month and I got a triangular region between the x-axis and the curve..I labeled this fundamental solution because I believe this is a fundamental problem in calculus in three dimensions not sure if that is the correct tag here.

Comment: drawing graphs helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know $3y\le x\le 3$ and $0\le y\le 1$, then $0\le 3y\le x\le 3$ in othe words
$0\le x\le 3$. On the other hand $0\le 3y\le x$

$$I=\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{\frac{x}{3}}e^{x^2}dydx=\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{3}xe^{x^2}dx$$